# Extract folders from zip in android

Tags: android, zip, unzip, directory

My application has to download a zip and has to unzip it in the application folder. The problem is that the zip doesn't have files but folders and in each folder there are different files. I would to keep the same structure but I don't know how do it. I succeed if i do it with a zip of files but not with a zip of folders. 
There is somebody who knows how do it?
Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-ziputils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create the directories for each directory entry in the ZIP archive. Here is a method I wrote and use that will keep the directory structure:

```
/**
 * Unzip a ZIP file, keeping the directory structure.
 *
 * @param zipFile
 *     A valid ZIP file.
 * @param destinationDir
 *     The destination directory. It will be created if it doesn't exist.
 * @return {@code true} if the ZIP file was successfully decompressed.
 */
public static boolean unzip(File zipFile, File destinationDir) {
  ZipFile zip = null;
  try {
    destinationDir.mkdirs();
    zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipFileEntries = zip.entries();
    while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
      ZipEntry entry = zipFileEntries.nextElement();
      String entryName = entry.getName();
      File destFile = new File(destinationDir, entryName);
      File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
      if (destinationParent != null && !destinationParent.exists()) {
        destinationParent.mkdirs();
      }
      if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry));
        int currentByte;
        byte data[] = new byte[DEFUALT_BUFFER];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, DEFUALT_BUFFER);
        while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, DEFUALT_BUFFER)) != EOF) {
          dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
        }
        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
        is.close();
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  } finally {
    if (zip != null) {
      try {
        zip.close();
      } catch (IOException ignored) {
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is the value for the constant  'EOF'?

Comment: @NidhinRejoice -1